# Image Button re-sizing issues

Tags: java, android, image, performance, android-layout

I have created a 6x7 board for a connect 4 game.
All the empty cells are image buttons.
When in portrait mode the board looks like this.

[image]

However, when I change orientation to landscape it looks like this.

[image]

The layout for one of the empty cells (Which I repeat) is

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/r6c4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/arrow4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/emptyBox"
    android:src="@drawable/empty"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

I am very new to android, can anyone point out how I may be able to resize the images to fit the landscape screen?

Thanks

Comment: you can make landscape layout for it

Comment: Ok, is there anything wrong with my XML currently that is causing the issue?